# react-navigation Error: Unable to resolve module `./vendor/index'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a react-native project and tried to upgrade version of react-navigation-stack and installed all missed libraries, but then I downgraded back and now I have error

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./vendor/index` from `node_modules/react-navigation-stack/lib/module/index.js`:
```

[image]

I have tried to remove node-modules and reinstall it, it doesn't work... 
What can I do?

```
"react-navigation": "4.0.10",
"react-navigation-redux-helpers": "4.0.1",
"react-navigation-stack": "1.10.3",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear you bundler cache: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/troubleshooting.html#im-getting-an-error-unable-to-resolve-module-after-updating-to-the-latest-version